# ggplot2 in sapply only returns a list but no plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, sapply

I have to create multiple plots for a report based on a selection of variables in my data.frame, but when I tried to use sapply for creating these plots I only got a list as an output and no plot was generated.

Here is a short example to illustrate my point:

```
tmp <- data.frame(effect=c(20, 30, 40, 50), prepost=c(1, 2), group=c("a", "a", "b", "b"))
select <- c("a", "b") 

sapply(1:length(select), function(t){
  ggplot(tmp[tmp$group==select[t], ], aes(x=prepost, y=effect)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
})
```

However it works when I use lapply instead of sapply:

```
lapply(1:length(select), function(t){
  ggplot(tmp[tmp$group==select[t], ], aes(x=prepost, y=effect)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
})
```

Can someone explain why it doesn't work with sapply as well?

Comment: `sapply` is intended to act like `lapply` but to attempt to simplify the result to a vector, matrix or array. So I would say simply that `sapply` is just the wrong tool for creating a list of plots.

Comment: Going off that, you could use a `simplify=FALSE` in you sapply which should work. `sapply(1:length(select), function(t){
  ggplot(tmp[tmp$group==select[t], ], aes(x=prepost, y=effect)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
},simplify=FALSE)
`

Comment: You should not use `*apply` functions for this. A `for` loop is more appropriate and cleaner syntax for this: `for (s in select)
  print(ggplot(tmp[tmp$group==s, ], aes(x=prepost, y=effect)) + 
          geom_bar(stat='identity'))`. Of course, you should use `ggsave` instead of `print`.